# Method 'range' of object _global failed when doing nothing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, visual-studio-macros

I have a big macro which basically processes some columns and spits out results based on some cross-checking with an access 2003 database. It works absolutely fine - no hitches at all.

However, I recently had to make a modification to it. It was literally changing an '8' to a '9' in one line of the code. But next time I ran it, it threw the `1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` error. Excel 2003 is a funny thing - I once scratched my head for hours over this, trying to find offending lines of code that could be causing the error, but alas to no avail. I did something that I didn't expect to trigger anything:

Starting with the original macro (100% confirmed working), if I just open the code up, and then save it so the 'last updated' metadata will update to reflect the save, though absolutely nothing has changed, it will throw that error again on opening.

It's as if it's so fragile that saving the macro as is will break it. Any ideas?

Update: here's what I changed that initially brought about the issue

```
iOutputCols = 9 'this was changed to 9 from 8
ReDim Preserve sOutputCols(iOutputCols)
sOutputCols(0) = "Policy No"
sOutputCols(1) = "Client"
sOutputCols(2) = "Trans"
sOutputCols(3) = "Effective Date"
sOutputCols(4) = "ClosingRef"
sOutputCols(5) = "Gross"
sOutputCols(6) = "Comm"
sOutputCols(7) = "Net Due"
sOutputCols(8) = "Risk"   'this line was added
```

Making the change here, while originally causing the error, doesn't seem special - I did small changes like the above elsewhere in the code and in other modules, one time I even did something as `testval = "test"` and even that redundant line will produce the error. The most minimalistic way to cause it? Simply open it up, save it without changing anything, and on next use the error occurs.

The error occurs at this line, in a completely different code section which is part of a form:

```
    If strErr <> "" Then MsgBox strErr, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Action Error"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'error occurs here, message box which shows me the error right above
```

End Sub

Update 2

Removing the error handling throws the error on this line

```
    Case "> Send Next Period Reminder" 'error on line below
        Call ReplaceText(wordApp, "[office_address]", Range("Address_" & Worksheets("UserParms").Range("F6").Value).Value) 'error this line
        Call ReplaceText(wordApp, "[office_address2]", Range("Address2_" & Worksheets("UserParms").Range("F6").Value).Value)
'more of the same replacetexts below
```

For context, this is when an option is selected for "Send Next Period Reminder", which pulls a word .dot template from a static folder and populates it based on the data selected within the sheet (Hence the replace texts). This is in a different module and has never been touched before.

Comment: Without a whole lot of code posted it's unlikely this will get answered before it gets closed as "too broad, too vague". Did anything else change? Libraries, versions, ... software update?

Comment: Do you have any UDF's in the workbook which might be triggering the error?  Without more information it's pretty much impossible to suggest what might be causing this.

Comment: @floris literally nothing changes - you can open it up, change nothing, save it, then when you try and run the macro next time it'll throw the error.

Comment: @TimWilliams no UDFs to speak of.

I would post code if I could, but the macro is comprised of over 10 modules totalling more than 9000 lines of code. Debugging at the point of the error gives no clues, so I've no idea where it could be coming from.

Comment: Have you tried "cleaning" the project by exporting, removing and then re-importing all the code?

Comment: @TimWilliams I had no idea that such a process existed! I'll have to look it up on how to do it. I'll give that a go and let you know.

Comment: This very good add-in from Rob Bovey will do it for you! http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams goodness, this macro just won't let me rest - it cleans other projects fine, but for the problematic one not even the cleaner works, throwing up an error "Application-defined or object-defined error (bExportAndRemove)"

Comment: Then you're down to the manual approach I guess...

Comment: @TimWilliams dang, that didn't work - I exported all the forms and modules, deleted them from the project, then reimported them. As this counted as a "change", the error has reoccurred :(

Comment: `It was literally changing an '8' to a '9' in one line of the code. But next time I ran it, it threw the 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed error.` Instead of guessing, I would like to see the code that you actually changed and the line which is giving you the error..

Comment: if you changed the `Sheets(8).Range...` to `Sheets(9).Range...` then you are most likely to see the error you've got as the parent object of `Range` class is not accessible. It may be that your `Sheet(9)` doesn't actually exist

Comment: @SiddharthRout original post edited, hope that helps

Comment: @mehow hi, that is true, though it is not the problem I'm experiencing. I have just updated the original post to give a clearer picture of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Remove your error handling and then tell us which line is giving you the error...

Comment: @nclfrk799 that was a wild guess as there was no code given. the code you have posted is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: The fact that any "change" breaks the project suggests that "recompiling" is the problem. Can you see if opening, compiling (not saving), and running will cause the issue too? I wonder if there is an `option base 0` vs `option base 1` type of thing sneaking in... Or that you are looping over all elements of `sOutputCols` and this results in the lookup of something that doesn't (yet) exist. I like @SiddharthRout's suggestion: remove (comment out) all `on error` statements to see what line (what reference to what object) is causing the issue.

Comment: @SiddharthRout ah yes, my bad. Error handling removed and the offending line is shown above after update 2.

Comment: @Floris I wasn't aware that VBA code was compiled? Or is it like a pseudo-compile?

Comment: @Floris I compiled it using the debug->compile VBA project option in the VBA editor, and yep, the problem appears as usual. It's like a save in that the timestamp of the workbook with the macro updated once I did the recompile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try properly qualifying your `Range` method calls.  You have lines like this:

```
    Call ReplaceText(wordApp, "[office_address]", Range("Address_" & Worksheets("UserParms").Range("F6").Value).Value) 'error this line
    Call ReplaceText(wordApp, "[office_address2]", Range("Address2_" & Worksheets("UserParms").Range("F6").Value).Value)
```

While it may not be obvious, there are cases, both environmental and code-based, where these unqualified uses of `Range` could fail.  Change the references like `Range("Address...` to something like `yourTargetWS.Range("Address..`.

Comment: oh my goodness...the problem has been fixed! Qualifying the range itself didn't actually fix the issue, but your solution did actually make me investigate why the underlying worksheet reference was empty or not.

I don't know why, but when I save it, elements of that sheet move permanently (3 cols across). Changing all instances of F6 to I6 solved it. 

I still don't know why the elements move upon saving, but at the moment I'm happy that it's been fixed. No more hair tearing!

Thanks for providing the catalyst to the answer!